# Share structure among different files in a project

Tags: c++, c

I want to share a structure among different files.
My problem is that I want to access a structure defined by a function in some file from another function defined in another file.

```
file1.c

    #include<struct.h>
    int main(){
    
    //I want to access test1 variables here
    
    printf("%d",test1.x);
    printf("%d",test1.y);
    .
    .
    }




file2.c
        
        #include<struct.h>
        int fun(){
        .
        struct test test1;
        test1.x=1;
        test1.y=13;
        .
        .
        .
        
        
        }
    

struct.h

struct test{
int x;
string y;
};
.
//Initialize some structure
.
.
}
```

Am I doing the right thing? Please tell me how can I do this.
I am not able to see the variable test1 in main().

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Looks reasonable. You should be more specific what problem you are facing (or if you just need some sort of confirmation).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I am not able to see test1 in my main().

Comment: Because that is a member of another function `f`

Comment: @SAM:So is there a way to do this.??

Comment: You can make `test1` a global variable...

Comment: Or you may return it from `f` and call `f` in your `main`

Comment: @SAM: return it from f and call f in your main....I think that will be the same situation..

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Almost. Your `#include` may need fixing.

Use:

```
#include "struct.h"
```

`<struct.h>` means it's found in the include path. (Defined in Project settings, usually only includes standard headers eg `<stdio.h>`. Sometimes it will include headers from external libraries)

The `#include "struct"` Means look locally. So if it's in the same folder it will find it. (Otherwise you would need a more detailed path)

Also you can't seed varibles accross functions. So the `test1` varible in `fun()` is not visible to any function (including `main()`). So you need to transfer the contents from `fun()` to `main()`.

One way to do this is to return it, `struct test1` is small doing this would work.

```
// file2.c
struct test fun() {
    ...
    struct test test1;
    test1.x = 1;
    test1.y = 2;
    ...
    return test1;
}

// file1.c    
int main() {
    struct test1 = fun();
    
    printf("%d\n %d\n", test1.x, test1.y);

    ...
}
```

The other way is the have `main()` own test1 and the give it to `fun()` using a pointer

```
int main() {
    ...
    struct test test1;

    // '&test1' means create a pointer to test1.
    fun( &test1 );

    printf("%d %d", test1.x, test1.y);
    ...
}

// "struct test *test1" means 'test1' is a pointer to a 'struct test'
int fun(struct test *test1) {
    ...
    // a->b is the same as (*a).b
    test1->x = 0;
    test1->y = 1;

    ...
}
```

(It also appears that test1.y is a `char*` and you were assigning it a number. This causes
bad things to happen, only assign `char*` to strings.

Comment: It's correct..But main() is not directly calling to fun()..fun() is called by some intermediate functions..

Comment: Ok then, you would need to decalre a global variable.

In `file2.c` decalre `struct test test1;` outside of funtions. Then in
`file1.c` or in `struct.c` decalre `extern struct test test1;`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 2 errors;

## include  ==> #include "struct.h"

make test1 global variable infile2.c.

add declaration in file1.c

```
extern struct test test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**struct.h:**

```
struct test{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

**file1.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

```
#include "struct.h"

int main() {

    extern struct test test1;    //test1 defined in another file.

    printf("%d",test1.x);
    printf("%d",test1.y);
}
```

**file2.c:**

```
#include "struct.h"

struct test test1 = {1, 13};     // Make it a global variable

int fun() {
    // struct test test1;    // member of f can't directly be used outside.
    // test1.x=1;
    // test1.y=13;

    return 0;
}
```

---

OR

**file1.c:**

`#include <stdio.h>`

```
#include "struct.h"

int main() {

    extern struct test test1;
    extern void f(struct test*);

    f(&test1);
    printf("%d",test1.x);
    printf("%d",test1.y);
}
```

**file2.c:**

```
#include "struct.h"


struct test test1 = {1, 13};

void fun(struct test *p) {

    p->x = 1;
    p->y = 2;
}
```

Comment: when I am initializing test1 members inside fun() then I am not able to get the values in the main()..some garbage is printing..

Comment: Because `test1` in `f` and the global `test1` (outside `f`) are different! That's why I commented `test1` in `f` to clear the confusion...

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to assign the value to test1 inside fun() and I want to use these values inside main()

Comment: Then you must pass the address of `test1` to `f`. And then assign values in `f`.

Comment: who will pass the address of test1 to fun()..Actually my main() is not directly calling to fun()..fun() is called by some intermediate functions..

Comment: See the edited answer...
I have called `fun` in main... The caller will pass the address to `fun`

Comment: Ok then let the caller of `fun` pass the address of `test1` to it.

Comment: In between Main() and calling of fun() so many functions are being called and lot of thins and calculations are happening..

Comment: As long as those "in between" things don't access or modify `test1` ti doesn't matter.
Btw if `fun` is intended for doing some another task than initializing `struct test` then you should not initialize `struct test` variables in `fun`.

Comment: In that case, instead of calling `fun`, you can just do: `test1.x = 1;` `test1.y = 13;` there...

Comment: :thnx..I am trying to extern the pointer variable..in fun() I have global pointer variable whicch is externed in main()...but when I try to print the value in main() it is giving garbage value..

Comment: ok and in which file is the global variable of which the pointer you are trying to extern?
Can you post it?

Comment: I think you are missing to initialize the pointer.
You must initialize that pointer with the address of the variable. Ex. `struct test *p = &test1;`